# overlay image with another transparent image

Tags: image-processing

I have two images I want to put one on top of the other and make the first one transparent . I am using this code but the transparency is not working at all. The second image is totally covering the first one. I am using C# , Framework 4.5 , Visual Studio 2012

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 

        Image imageBackground = Image.FromFile(@"e:\picstest\profile.png");
        Image imageOverlay = SetImageOpacity(Image.FromFile(@"e:\picstest\flag.png"), 50);


        Image img = new Bitmap(imageBackground.Width, imageBackground.Height);

        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(imageBackground, new Point(0, 0));
            gr.DrawImage(imageOverlay, new Point(0, 0));

        }

        string outputFileName = @"e:\picstest\output.png";
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                img.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

    }

    public static Image SetImageOpacity(Image img, float opacity)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height); // Determining Width and Height of Source Image
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        ColorMatrix colormatrix = new ColorMatrix();
        colormatrix.Matrix33 = opacity;
        ImageAttributes imgAttribute = new ImageAttributes();
        imgAttribute.SetColorMatrix(colormatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
        graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttribute);
        graphics.Dispose();   // Releasing all resource used by graphics 
        return bmp;
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: It might be an idea to mention your language, your Operating System and the libraries/tools you are using.

Comment: Why are you using `ImageFormat.Jpeg` when JPEG doesn't support transparency?

Comment: I changed to png and it didnt work , same results.

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed by putting the opacity value as lesser than 1 , apparently more than 1 makes it not transparent.